SWIFT or IFSC code formatter in android jetpack compose TextField editable
Ex: 23456-232
while typing above card number. we want to auto populate immediately - after 5th digit typed, then, user can enter last 3 digits.
how to achieve this in Jetpack compose in android.

Do you have a list of credit cards to autocomplete from? What do you expect to happen lets say user type 23, and there are 2 or more credit cards in your list? Also after how many digits you want auto complete to be invoked? And you will let only user enter last 3 digits right? What about erasing, how will your erase logic work?

actually, this is seperate country code requirement. Like IFSC. so, no credit card list available. I have above Swift/cpa code format only. so, i am trying to achieve above format only.

You can write a custom VisualTransformation to format user entries in XXXXX-XXX format with
class SwiftVisualTransformation : VisualTransformation {
    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
        return swiftFilter(text)
    }
}

fun swiftFilter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
    val trimmed = if (text.text.length >= 8) text.text.substring(0..7) else text.text
    var out = ""
    for (i in trimmed.indices) {
        out += trimmed[i]
        if (i == 4) out += "-"
    }

    val swiftOffsetTranslator = object : OffsetMapping {
        override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
            if (offset <= 4) return offset
            if (offset <= 8) return offset + 1
            return 9
        }

        override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
            if (offset <= 5) return offset
            if (offset <= 8) return offset - 1
            return 8
        }
    }

    return TransformedText(AnnotatedString(out), swiftOffsetTranslator)
}

And apply it
@Preview
@Composable
fun SwiftVisualTransformationSample() {

    var swift by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    OutlinedTextField(
        value = swift,
        label = { Text("Swift") },
        placeholder = { Text(text = "") },
        onValueChange = { newValue ->
            if (newValue.length <= 8) {
                swift = newValue
            }
        },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.NumberPassword),
        maxLines = 1,
        visualTransformation = SwiftVisualTransformation()
    )
}


Integrated with BasicTextField. Above answer is working fine. Thank you
